# Play Framework with MongoDB and Jongo

Tags: mongodb, playframework, jongo

How do I set up a Play project to use MongoDB with Jongo?

So far I have installed MongoDB but I don't know how to add it to my Play project, I don't think the documentation tells you how.

http://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo-1.1/home

I also can't follow the Jongo documentation. All it says is "choose a driver's version, finally download Jongo and you're all set".

http://jongo.org

How and where do I choose a driver's version, what do I put in the config file and what are the steps taken to install Jongo?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Benoit's spikes](https://github.com/bguerout/jongo-play2-spike) on the matter, I guess it will help.